# Create the relationship table between 2 tables in asp.net mvc EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I created:

- custom custom membership provider
- custom role provider
- an user model
- an role model

It create me the 2 custom tables correctly.
Now I want to create the table between Users and Roles with 2 columns: RoleId, UserId

I should I tweak my models to teach to EF to create this relationship table (UsersInRole)?

User model:

```
 public class User
{

    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Int32 CompanyId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String UserName { get; set; }

    public String Password { get; set; }

    public String PasswordSalt { get; set; }

    public String Email { get; set; }

    public Boolean IsApproved { get; set; }

    public Boolean IsLockedOut { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastLoginDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastPasswordChangedDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastLockoutDate { get; set; }

}
```

Role model:

```
public class Role
{

    [Key]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<string> AssignedUsers { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using code-first EF, then all you should need to do is add a collection of the Users to the Role class and vice-versa. EF takes this two-way link as a signal to create a many-to-many relationship in the underlying data store. To summarize, your classes would be augmented something like this...

```
public class User
{
  ...

  List<Role> Roles {get; set;}

}

public class Role
{
  ...

  List<User> Users {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Role
{

    [Key]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> AssignedUsers { get; set; }

}


 public class User
{

    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Int32 CompanyId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String UserName { get; set; }

    public String Password { get; set; }

    public String PasswordSalt { get; set; }

    public String Email { get; set; }

    public Boolean IsApproved { get; set; }

    public Boolean IsLockedOut { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastLoginDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastPasswordChangedDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastLockoutDate { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Role> Roles{ get; set; }

}
```